# Customize springboard in Android?

Tags: android, widget, homescreen

How can the home screen be customized? and also how can the springboard layout be customized?

I want to make an application which makes a clone of users current theme and allows user to customize content that he wants to view such as phonebook, pics and etc.

Comment: Springboard is iPhone, not Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can the home screen be customized?

You can write your own home screen application.

> and also how can the springboard layout be customized?

What is "the springboard layout"?

Comment: How can we write homescreen application? Springboard layout is the one where we can see all the applications on Android device. I think its Iphone term. For example there is an application called sweeter home in Android market. Also, can you let me know how to develop our own homescreen application?

Comment: @sunil: "How can we write homescreen application?" -- there is a sample Home screen app in your SDK. Look in the `samples/` directory. It is mostly a matter of adding the `HOME` category to an activity's `<intent-filter>`. "Springboard layout is the one where we can see all the applications on Android device." -- that's the "launcher".

Comment: @CommonsWare The term "springboard" is Apple iOS terminology for the home screen.  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/841640/iphone-what-is-springboard-do-i-need-to-care