# Why SpringBoard failed to launch application with error: -3

Tags: ios7, xcode5

I am new to iOS 7, I am getting SpringBoard failed to launch application with error: -3 with Xcode 5

Comment: delete your application from simulator..exit from simulator..clean the application and than re- run your application.. this may solve issue..

Comment: yes that I know, I asked why I am getting this error. so I can avoid from next time.

Comment: I think it's because of the new xccheckout file which is causing

Comment: This is the most annoying thing in Xcode 5, I never saw this before 5 and I get tired of it these days, I thought it might be related to Mavericks some how or the 64-bit aspect of the Simulator. Either way I see this error a lot and it makes me feel like I'm developing for Android or something...

Comment: This is duplicate question. Solution is posted over here : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19855222/springboard-failed-to-launch-application-with-error-3/20236097#20236097                  Hope this one helps!

Comment: @JayprakashDubey please check the question posted date and then tell which question is duplicated, and thanks for your note.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to permanently fix Xcode 5 SpringBoard failed to launch application with error: -3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18883942/how-to-permanently-fix-xcode-5-springboard-failed-to-launch-application-with-err)

Comment: @KyleClegg Clegg thanks for knowing about this, but I was looking for reason/cause of the above error, not for the solution to fix this error,though there are many questions which are similar to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible reason: too little available RAM.  This happened for me (old iMac with only 3GB of RAM, running too many apps at once) as I addressed in this answer:

[iPhone Simulator: SpringBoard failed to launch application with error: 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300793/iphone-simulator-springboard-failed-to-launch-application-with-error-7/20765898#20765898)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this happens when you modify the elements in the Interface Builder: 
Try the following methods, if you are sure all your elements are properly hooked in IB

1.Clen build by:  CMD+SHIFT+K
2. Go to Project Navigator->Select your project->General 
Then Deployment Info-> Devices, then Toggle Bettween iPad and iPhone, 
Thats is to say, if your project was targeted for iPad, then select iPhone, then Reselect iPad 
. 
See image below: 
[image]
Then run the project, you should be good to go.

Comment: I tried this. But also found that the simulator was running in the background. Please check that!

Comment: that was no the ultimate answer, but it helps to resolve the issue sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

When you will get this " SpringBoard failed to launch application with error: -3 " error, just use following solutions,

**Solution 1 :**

- Just quit Simulator
- Goto product menu
- Clean project
- Now build app

This will not show this Alert again.

**Solution 2 :**

- If the problem still occurs then delete the App from Simulator
- Re-run the code.

This will work since the app contents are loaded freshly...

Hope this will work for you....!!!